# Variance in a CSV file after uploading it in shiny [R]

Tags: r, csv, shiny, shinydashboard

I have made a fileInput which loads the .CSV file[dataset] directly after user has chosen it.

```
data <- data.frame(A=c(2.076,3.99,4.95,5.99,6.578,7.6.7),B=c(3.000,7.980,8.0001,9.001,2.000,1.056,2.789,3.546),C=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2))
```

In ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    fileInput('file', 'Choose CSV file',
            accept=c('csv', 'comma-separated-values','.csv')),
    ))
```

Problem : I am not getting variance values

```
 In server.r
  library(shiny)
 library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

    d<-reactive({
            if (is.null(input$file))
                    return(NULL)                
            d<-read.csv(input$file$datapath)
            d <- transform(data, D= A+B, E= A-B) 
            d <- transform(data, var1 =var(D), var2= var(E))
             d
             # In table I am getting variance value as 0.00 
             })
```

Comment: Would this `data <- transform(data, D= A+B, E= A-B)` work for you?

Comment: @akrun thank you so much it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 data <- transform(data, D= A+B, E= A-B)
```

Comment: I have just edited my question can you help me with this

Comment: @janvigiri  Please check your example, it is giving me errors.

Comment: @janvigiri  Suppose your data is `data <- data.frame(A=c(2.076,3.99,4.95,5.99,6.5, 7, 8,7.6),B=c(3.000,7.980,8.0001,9.001,2.000,1.056,2.789,3.546),C=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1));data <- transform(data, D= A+B, E= A-B);transform(data, var1 =var(D), var2= var(E))` works for me